# Can I change dynasty in a single player game?

Tags: tropico-5

Some weird bug happened where my singleplayer dynasty became out of sync and it made a second dynasty... Is it possible to select a different dynasty in the single player campaign after one has been started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can change you dynasty is to start your game all over and start from scratch with an all new family.